# How to make black glow in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, rendering, post-processing

I don't know why I cant find this anywhere online, but I'm creating a character for my game and I want him to almost glow black because he's a shadow person. Of course I cant use bloom since that only works for colours with brightness, and I cant use a light because a black light just wouldn't do anything. so I'm very confused I don't see why this wouldn't be possible, I mean I'm not a unity developer but surely making something glow black isn't that hard. right?

Ive tried using a particle system, but it didn't give the results I wanted. Some particles cluster together and create an ugly effect and also having less opaque particles results in them overlapping and having patchy transparent and opaque spots. It also slows the game down a lot compared to a basic glow effect like I need. Of course if there's ways to circumvent this *using* a particle system I'm open to suggestions.

Here is an example of "black glow" https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eMAczq5WtXo/VWb3afZBODI/AAAAAAAAA7c/GXAaFg8D48k/s1600/17.png

Comment: Define what you mean by "black glow".  It's obviously not possible to have a glow that is absent light, so are you talking about shading the area around the character, slightly darker than it would otherwise be?

Comment: by "glow" which yes obviously isn't possible but then way I imagine it is say having a white character that glows white, and then inverting the colours, so you end up with a black character with a black "glow",

Comment: i guess you could call it a shadow around the player

Comment: Have you tried a grey glow?

Comment: a grey glow would probably look weird on a solid black player and the bloom intensity would need to be high as grey is still pretty dark, with a bloom intensity that high it would mess the rest of the view up and be too bright

Comment: So my other thought was transparency. Render the core of the character opaque, and the outer edges progressively more transparent.

Comment: bloom wouldn't work at all for a pitch black "glow" since black literally means "no light emission at all" ... so what exactly are you actually trying to achieve? ^^ Have you seen anything in real live glow black? Usually that's not a thing so it's a bit hard to understand what effect you want exactly .. could you add a picture?

Comment: i pretty much gave up on this idea but this is what i mean https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-eMAczq5WtXo/VWb3afZBODI/AAAAAAAAA7c/GXAaFg8D48k/s1600/17.png

Comment: You can try using a light with its BlendMode set to Multiply or Subtractive.

Comment: I feel like that could work, however im using a 2D Renderer and 2D Lights dont have an option for subtract, they have one for multiply but black doesnt work with multiply.